# Link is not opening in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I have such code, that work on my Console Project in VS2012 for Desktop, but not work in VS2013 for WP8.

```
url = "http://lenta.ru/photo/2014/06/23/blackwidow/"

WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync(); /*from here programm doesn't work on wp8, but works on PC Console Project on VS2012*/
Stream data = response.GetResponseStream();
```

Why this code work on console project, but not work from my WP8 app?

fix.
Problem is solved by using HttpCLient instead of WebRequest.

```
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
 try
 {
     var result = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
 }
 catch
 {

 }
 client.Dispose();
```

Comment: Please make sure you are tagging your questions correctly

Comment: I've solved that problem by using HttpClient.

Comment: If you solved your problem then make sure to post it below. This isn't your personal Q and A... It's to document common problems and solutions for everyone. Someone else will likely have this problem in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved by using HttpCLient instead of WebRequest.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
try
{
    var result = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
}
catch
{

}
client.Dispose();
```